# keeping current user session active with parse?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I've used the following code in my `ViewDidLoad()` to keep the current user session active :

```
let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()

        if currentUser != nil {
            let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let mainViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabby") as! TabController

            self.presentViewController(mainViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

However it seems to not work. When the app is terminated and re-opened, the login/sign up screen is presented again, instead of the view which the user was left on in the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on an app with parse that requires the user to login or sign up, and it also checks when there is a user, and if the user it's online, it keeps the user signed in. 
Are you using a custom login and sign up? or are you using the parse sign up?
There's a video that helped me tackle those problems, here's the link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sL47vpWTMU

He explains how to work with parse and a custom login, and also how to make your own custom login with parse, so it checks that the user it's logged in, or not.

I hope it helps!